# Com Port Access Denied while Uploading Python sketch to the Node mcu in Pycharm

Tags: python, windows, pycharm, nodemcu, micropython

I am running simple sketch in pycharm . But While uploading Its showing like this

```
raise PyboardError('failed to access ' + device)
ampy.pyboard.PyboardError: failed to access COM4 
Connecting to COM4
Uploading files: 0% (0/1)
```

I am Running pycharm in Windows , i am not able to give com port access

please help me out

Thank you

Comment: Did you install the USB drivers for your board?

Comment: Thank you for your reply .Yes , I can upload sketch through Arduino ide successfully . But in the pycharm it showing  like that

Comment: its the same COM port in Arduino? Do you close Arduino when using pycharm? COM port cannot be used by multiple apps simultaneously.

Comment: @Lixas Thank  you for your reply and sorry for my late reply.  I have closed all ports . Only opened Pycharm .But still getting same error. Do you please suggest any way to give access to the com port in windows ...